# Custom string sorting in java

Tags: java, sorting

i have wrote a java program in java to sort strings alphabetically . The problem is when it sorts string having roman numerals it treats it as character and sorts accordingly

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
public class SampleCustomSortApp
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> titles =new ArrayList();
        titles.add("java");
        titles.add("J-IV");
        titles.add("A-V");
        titles.add("J-V");
        titles.add("J-IX");
        titles.add("J-XX");
        titles.add("J-X");
        titles.add("J-I");
        titles.add("J-II");

        titles.add("datawarehouse");
        titles.add("oracledba");
        System.out.println("Before Sorting Elements Are :"+titles+"\n");
        Collections.sort(titles, new MyCustomCompator());
        System.out.println("After Sorting Elements Are :"+titles);
    }
}
class MyCustomCompator implements Comparator
{
    public int compare(Object s1,Object s2)
    {
        String one = (String)s1;
        String two = (String)s2;
        /* for ascending order */
        if(one.compareTo(two)>0){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Actual Output

```
Before Sorting Elements Are :[java, J-IV, A-V, J-V, J-IX, J-XX, J-X, J-I, J-II, datawarehouse, oracledba]

After Sorting Elements Are :[A-V, J-I, J-II, J-IV, J-IX, J-V, J-X, J-XX, datawarehouse, java, oracledba]
```

Desired Output

```
Before Sorting Elements Are :[java, J-IV, A-V, J-V, J-IX, J-XX, J-X, J-I, J-II, datawarehouse, oracledba]

After Sorting Elements Are :[A-V, J-I, J-II, J-IV,  J-V,J-IX, J-X, J-XX, datawarehouse, java, oracledba]
```

should i use regex expression to compare the strings. can some tell me the solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You definitely need your own `Comparator` which appropriately parses the Roman numerals. The job of parsing has (naturally) already been solved, so you just need to split your strings into alphabetic and numeral parts. See [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Roman_numerals/Decode#Java_2) for an example of Roman numeral parsing code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to extract the roman numerals in the strings you could use a roman numeral parser in your Comparator.  Replace the roman numerals with arabic numerals and then compare the strings.  You'll have to left-pad the arabic numerals with zeroes so they all have the same number of digits.  Here's an example of such a parser in Java at [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Roman_numerals/Decode#Java_2).